# FFmpeg Libraries: How Do I Convert a Video to 4 Level Grayscale Video at 160x100 Pixels and as Raw Data

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg

This seems like an odd question, so I am going to start from the beginning:

I am a calculator programmer, specifically a Ti-89 programmer, and I'm trying to make a video player for it. I have the code for the calculator side done already, but I need to be able to convert video to a specific format that works as follows:

Each frame is 4 level grayscale, where there are 2 bytes for every 8 horizontal pixels, a "back," or dark byte, and a "front," or light byte. Basically, every frame is 2 monochrome binary images, with the first byte of the first one is followed by the first byte of the second one, so data is stored as follows:

```
FB(front buffer)[1],BB(back buffer)[1],FB[2],BB[2], etc...
```

Here's how the display works: (defining 0 as white and 3 as black, with 1 and 2 being in-between shades)
Each front buffer bit is worth 1, so if the front buffer were displayed with nothing in the back buffer, the "1" (or true) bits would show up as light gray pixels. These are then added to the back buffer bits, which are worth 2 (so if the back buffer were displayed with nothing in the front buffer, the "1" (or true) bits would show up as dark gray pixels) to get:

"0" bit on either buffer = white pixel (0+0=0)

"1" bit on front buffer but not back buffer = light gray pixel (1+0=1)

"1" bit on back buffer but not front buffer = dark gray pixel (0+2=2)

"1" bit on both buffers = black pixel (1+2=3)

I have this down calculator-side, but I need to know: 1) How to convert the video to a specific framerate using the libs 2) How to convert these frames to 4-level grayscale at 160x100 pixels and 3) How to save these frames as raw data in the format I described. Thank you in advance for your answer(s).